# Some of my mac java programs won't open/work

Tags: java

When I type "`java -version`" into the terminal it says :

```
 "Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
  Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)"
```

But when I open my system preferences and try to click on Java is says:

```
 "“Java” can’t be opened because it isn’t available."
```

I don't know what that means but the real problem is that when I try to run/open some *.jar files* a pop-up comes up saying that this java file can't be opened check the console.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `java` is not installed on your machine.

From the [docs](https://java.com/en/download/faq/java_mac.xml), you can check if java is installed, the following way:

> Mac OS X 10.6 and below: Apple's Java comes pre-installed with your
> Mac OS.
>
> Mac OS X 10.7 (Lion) and above: Java is not pre-installed
> with Mac OS X versions 10.7 and above. To get the latest Java from
> Oracle, you will need Mac OS X 10.7.3 and above.  If you have Java 7
> or later versions, you will see a Java icon under **System Preferences**.
> Java versions 6 and below are listed in the Java Preferences.app
> located in the Applications > Utilities folder on your Mac.

You can find the java installation instruction for Mac [here](https://java.com/en/download/help/mac_install.xml).